# Why doesn't Perl find my script when I use the -I switch?

Tags: perl, shell, command

I have googled a way to do this kind of thing.

I use this shell command:

```
perl -I/p2 maxconnect4.p1 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

My pl files and pm files are all in "p2" directory.

However, it gives me an error:

```
Can't open perl script "maxconnect4.pl": No such file or directory
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `-I` doesn't apply to files specified on the command line, only to modules loaded with `require` or `use`.
2. You shouldn't use relative directories with `-I`.  If your script does a `chdir`, then that directory is now relative to the *new* current directory, not the one that was current when the script started.  (In many cases, you can get away with breaking this rule, because most of the time, modules are loaded as the script starts, before it has changed directories.)

   And you aren't actually using a relative directory anyway, because you said `-I/p2`, which means to look in a directory named `/p2`, not in a subdirectory named `p2` in the current directory (which is what you wanted to say).

Try:

```
perl -I$PWD/p2 p2/maxconnect4.pl arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

(assuming you're using a Unix-type shell).

In many cases, a better solution is to have the script set up `@INC` automatically.  At the top of `p2/maxconnect4.pl` (before you load any modules from `p2`, put):

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
```

[`use lib`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib) is the programmatic version of the `-I` switch, and [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) tells your script the pathname of the directory in which it is located.  Then you can just say:

```
perl p2/maxconnect4.pl arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

and not have to bother with `-I` at all.

Comment: Yes, I should absolute directory. Thanks very much. It works.

Answer (score 3):

`perl` needs a real file to be executed. You have to call it through its absolute or relative path:

```
perl -I p2 p2/maxconnect4.pl arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I have tried your way. It gives me a new error:

Comment: If I go the directory p2, and use command:  perl maxconnect4.pl arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4. It works well. I guess this is the problem of the search path. I'm totally new to Perl. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is the file AiPlayer.pm physically on your harddrive?